# How to merge with mercurial

Tags: macos, mercurial, merge, bitbucket

I created a repo and made some changes into a file. Then I committed and kept working. A couple of changes and I committed again. 
I had to go back to the first version, so I did:

```
hg up 5f01300
```

And the files from the first version came back.

I made some changes and committed again.

```
hg commit -m 'Updated'
```

A new head was created and then I tried:

```
hg push
```

Mercurial said there were *"outstanding uncommitted"* stuffs.

I tried to commit again:

```
hg commit -m 'Changes accepted'
```

Then I typed:

```
hg merge
```

So a lot of errors appeared because there were two heads and I couldn't merge them.

Sometimes I try to merge like I did above and it works perfectly. Usually at the second time I try to repeat the process, it breaks and I can't merge anything.

Can somebody teach how to merge properly?

### [SOME ERRORS]

Usually, at the second time, this is what happens:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("hello, world!\n");
<<<<<<< local
        printf("sure am glad I'm not using CVS!\n");
=======
        printf("sure am glad I'm using Mercurial!\n");
>>>>>>> other
        return 0;
}
```

And I have to do:

```
hg resolve -m hello.c
```

Comment: It sounds like there are merge conflicts (multiple heads are just different [anonymous] branches). See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialMerge and http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TutorialConflict - also make sure merging is done into a *clean* branch

Comment: (You'll have to explain what "a lot of errors" and "it breaks" means for more specific advice.)

Comment: That's just a normal merge conflict. Do what it says. Or use a tool like kdiff3 (which is what I normally recommend) to handle conflicts visually during the merge operation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003588/how-resolve-this-mercurial-conflict for how to configure (and use) the kdiff3 tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merging is how you combine divergent versions of your files. Whenever you change a file in two different ways, Mercurial will try to merge it when you run `hg merge`.

When the changes to the files don't overlap, Mercurial can do the merge automatically. However, if you change the same line in two different ways, then you need to help Mercurial merge the two edits.

Consider a file that starts with `hello, world!` in the first revision and then changes into `sure am glad I'm not using CVS!` in the second revision:

```
"hello, world" --- "sure am glad I'm not using CVS!"
```

You now update back to the first revision and make a different change to the text:

```
"hello, world" --- "sure am glad I'm not using CVS!"
               \
                \
                 \
                   "sure am glad I'm using Mercurial!"
```

You now have a *divergent* history and when you `hg merge`, Mercurial will tell you that it has detected a *conflict* in the file. Mercurial will search for a [merge tool](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/merge-tools) and if it cannot find any on your system, it will dump the conflicting changes in the file. The file then looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< local
sure am glad I'm not using CVS!
=======
sure am glad I'm using Mercurial!
>>>>>>> other
```

The markers you see are called *merge markers* and they show you the region of the file that couldn't be automatically merged. The top region marked with `local` is the version you had in your working copy before you typed `hg merge`. The bottom region marked `other` is the version that was on the branch you merged with.

Mercurial knows that the file is unresolved and you can see with with `hg resolve --list`. You now edit the file to somehow combine the two versions. Here's one combination:

```
sure am glad I'm using Mercurial and not CVS!
```

I've deleted the merge markers and left behind a version I like. You now mark the file as resolved and commit the merge:

```
$ hg resolve --mark hello.c
$ hg commit
```

I hope that helps!

---

Another comment: You write

> [...] I tried: `hg push`. Mercurial said there were "outstanding uncommitted" stuffs.

Mercurial never talks about uncommitted changes when you try to push. Pushing and pulling are *unrelated* to your working copy (where your uncommitted changes live). So it is okay to push and pull with a dirty working copy. The error you're thinking of is probably

```
$ hg merge
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
$ hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges
```

That is, you cannot start a new merge before you commit or abort the current merge.